# Admin panel implement in parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, admin, panel

Can we manage admin panel for mobile application in parse.com ? Besides web services for mobile application , we need to manage admin panel in parse.com . Does parse.com allow to manage admin panel ?

Comment: Yes.  The web sdks do what the mobile ones do.

Comment: Thanks danh . I will definitely go through the web sdks .